# Composer Template: new map keeps old position and scale

Tags: qgis, print-composer, print-templates, composer-manager

I've made a Composer Template that includes a map.
When I use that template with another project, the new map is loaded, but the view is set to the old coordinates/position and the old scale of the original project I made the template in.
How can I accomplish that, when I use that template in a new project, the map in the template gets the new position and scale?

Comment: Are you asking [how to set map canvas top match main canvas extent](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_map.html#the-toolbar)?

Comment: @Erik Yes, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: @Erik Can it be automated?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz yes, thank you